# No Such module whenever import any class swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have swift 4 project, recently pull from another branch. But whenever i want to import any class which is already exist in project show me the error `"No such module..."`. Please suggest me what is wrong. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to import files in Swift as they are globally available. In Swift you can only import module, e.g. any framework.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, if a class already exist in project then you don't need to import it; you can directly use its properties by creating its instance. but if you have problem with it then you need to check target membership for the class. it should be checked for the project like in my example in pics[image]

[image]